# how to show the result in php after calculating 2 variables and print it to excel Cell using SQLServer?

Tags: php, sql-server, excel, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

i'm new in sqlserver and PHP ..and i want to export data to excel using PHP .
and  did some Minus calculating in export to excel php line which is :

```
 $sheet->setCellValue('K' . $i, $row['kompensasi']);
 $sheet->setCellValue('L' . $i, $row['Potongan_absen']);
 $sheet->setCellValue('M' . $i, $row['kompensasi'] - $row['Potongan_absen']);
```

and what i want to do is.. if the result of **($row['kompensasi'] - $row['Potongan_absen'])** is less than 0.. print 0 in excel Cell but if the result is equal 0 or bigger . print the total inside excel cell ..

i dont know how to do that .. i tried like this but the result  :

```
    $total_Insentif =sqlsrv_fetch_array($row['kompensasi'] - $row['Potongan_absen']);
    if($total_Insentif < 0){
        $sheet->setCellValue('M' . $i, $row['kompensasi'] - $row['Potongan_absen']);
    }else{
        $sheet->setCellValue('M' . $i, '0');
    }
```

sorry for my bad english . if there something is hard to understand it .. just tell me and i wil try to explain :) .

Comment: Hint: `$sheet->setCellValue('M' . $i, max(0, $row['kompensasi'] - $row['Potongan_absen']));`

Comment: THANK YOU SOO MUCH BROTHER .. THAT EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR .. THANKS U AGAIN @Zhorov can teach me is it possible to make the excel create new sheet for every month. bcz now when i choose date range and download all result with different month will be in one sheet . and thank u again brother